# Unity A* graph won't scale with canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, graph, scale, path-finding

I am using the A* graph package that I found here.

https://arongranberg.com/astar/download

it all works well in scene view and I was able to set the graph to treat walls like obstacles.

[image]

However once I start the game the canvas scales and the graph's nodes no longer align with the walls.

[image]

this is really messing up my path finding. If anyone has any ideas how to fix this that would be much appreciated. I tried parenting the graph to the canvas but it still doesn't scale.

Kind regards

Comment: This product has a forum, probably best to ask there : https://forum.arongranberg.com/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this what we did is edited the script of the A* code, in the update function we just got it to rescan once. This means that once the game started and all the scaling had taken place the graph re adjusted its bounds. This is probably not the most proper way but it only took four lines and worked for us.

```
private bool scanAgain = true;
    private void Update () {
        // This class uses the [ExecuteInEditMode] attribute
        // So Update is called even when not playing
        // Don't do anything when not in play mode
        if (!Application.isPlaying) return;

        navmeshUpdates.Update();

        // Execute blocking actions such as graph updates
        // when not scanning
        if (!isScanning) {
            PerformBlockingActions();
        }

        // Calculates paths when not using multithreading
        pathProcessor.TickNonMultithreaded();

        // Return calculated paths
        pathReturnQueue.ReturnPaths(true);

        
        if (scanAgain)
        {
            Scan();
            scanAgain = false;
        }
```